# Python Tkinter button not appearing?

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I'm new to tkinter and I have this code in python:

```
#import the tkinter module
from tkinter import *
import tkinter


calc_window = tkinter.Tk()
calc_window.title('Calculator Program')


button_1 = tkinter.Button(text = '1', width = '30', height = '20')
button_1 = '1'

calc_window.mainloop()
```

But when I run it, the button doesn't appear. Does anyone know why? Thank you!

Comment: you need to add the button to calc_window

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you do `from tkinter import *` and
`import tkinter`? This is redundant. In general, stick to the latter option.

Comment: Why don't you just google "tkinter button"? The first hit leads to this excellent example filled page : http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Answer (score 3):

Getting a widget to appear requires two steps: you must create the widget, and you must add it to a layout. That means you need to use one of the geometry managers `pack`, `place` or `grid` to position it somewhere in its container.

For example, here is one way to get your code to work:

```
button_1 = tkinter.Button(text = '1', width = '30', height = '20')
button_1.pack(side="top")
```

The choice of `grid` or `pack` is up to you. If you're laying things out in rows and columns, `grid` makes sense because you can specify rows and columns when you call `grid`. If you are aligning things left-to-right or top-to-bottom, `pack` is a little simpler and designed for such a purpose.

Note: `place` is rarely used because it is designed for precise control, which means you must manually calculate x and y coordinates, and widget widths and heights. It is tedious, and usually results in widgets that don't respond well to changes in the main window (such as when a user resizes). You also end up with code that is somewhat inflexible.

An important thing to know is that you can use both `pack` and `grid` together in the same program, but you cannot use both on different widgets that have the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter


calc_window = tkinter.Tk()
calc_window.title('Calculator Program')
frame = Frame(calc_window )
frame.pack()


button_1 = tkinter.Button(frame,text = '1', width = '30', height = '20')
button_1.pack(side=LEFT)


calc_window.mainloop()
```

try adding the button using pack(). i donno why u tried to assign `button_1 = '1'` in your code

a neat example:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(
            frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit
            )
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Button needs a container into which to be packed, which is not the case in your first example.

Comment: @mhawke please check now

Comment: That's better. What happens when you run it?

Comment: @mhawke present system doesnt have tkinter installed

Answer (score 0):

You're not packing the button_1. The code is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Calculator Program')

button_1 = Button(root, text='1', width='30', height='20')
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It's simple!
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

calc_window = Tk()

calc_window.title('Calculator Program')

button_1 = Button(text = '1')

button_1.place(x=0,y=0,width = 30, height = 20)

calc_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: A short explanation might also help (even if it is somewhat obvious here).