# Tkinter - display buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, google-drive-api

I want to create 3 buttons and display list using Tkinter with functions listfile, download, upload and refresh.

Only listfile worked, 3 buttons didn't show up when I run. Did I do something wrong or just missing some steps ?

Here is my code:

main.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
from quickstart import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Hello")

def Upload():
    try:
        path = filedialog.askopenfile()
        FilePath=path.name
        Uploadfile(FilePath)
    except(AttributeError):
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("wanring" ,"No file choice!!!")
def DownLoad():
    indexs = listBox1.curselection()
    for i in indexs:
        Downloadfile(i,listBox1.get(i))

def Refresh():
    listBox1.delete(0,END)
    items = listfile()
    for item in items:
        listBox1.insert(items.index(item),str(items.index(item))+") "+item['name'])
    listBox1.pack()


lb1=Label(root,text="Connect with driver!!",font=("Times New Roman",14),fg="red")
lb1.pack(side = TOP)
# list name and index of items
lb2=Label(root)
lb2.pack(side = BOTTOM)
####
items = listfile()
listBox1 = Listbox(lb2,width=50,height=50,xscrollcommand=True)
for item in items:
    listBox1.insert(items.index(item),str(items.index(item))+") "+item['name'])
listBox1.pack()
#3 button
pnw1=PanedWindow(lb2,orient=HORIZONTAL)
pnw1.pack()
btnSelect=tkinter.Button(pnw1,text=("Upload"),command=Upload,bg='blue',fg='red')
pnw1.add(btnSelect)
btnDow=tkinter.Button(pnw1,text=("Download"),command=DownLoad,bg='blue',fg='red')
pnw1.add(btnDow)
btnDow=tkinter.Button(pnw1,text=("Refresh"),command=Refresh,bg='blue',fg='red')
pnw1.add(btnDow)

root.mainloop()
```

The `quickstart` file you can find [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mkh8XsJshM/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter button not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490475/python-tkinter-button-not-appearing)

Comment: Are you sure this is google drive api problem it can be tkinter problem too. Try that functions without tkinter(just call them from python code and see if it works). Also I recommend to use debugging tools it helps finding errors much easier

Comment: to find the problem I need to have code for google drive too.

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mkh8XsJshM/ this is from quickstart.py

Comment: @DaImTo i guess it's not tkinter problem

Comment: Google drive api returns data,  it does not show buttons. I fail to see how it could be a drive problem.

Comment: You should not use `Label` as the parent of the listbox and the three buttons.  Use `Frame` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the problem is in

> listBox1 = Listbox(lb2,width=50,height=50,xscrollcommand=True)

The Listbox takes too much sapce. Try to reduce the height.